# jQuery - DateTimePicker - Make time required to remove the current time

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

So I am using jQuery DateTimePicker, currently I have the following settings:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');

    jQuery('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        format: 'd/m/Y H:i a',
        minDate: 0,             
        minTime: 0,
        step: "30",
         allowTimes:[
          '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30',
          '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00'
         ]              
    });         

  });
```

As you can see, you can't select a date or time in the past and the time selection is only 9-5pm on weekdays...

This issue I have is that if I just select today's date, it put's in the date with the current time stamp, I need to somehow round this up to the next 30 minute increment or make the time selection required as well as the date.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I managed to find a solution in the end, here is the updated code:

I've also made some further changes so today's date is not selectable if it's outside the `allowTimes`.

Since it puts the current time as well, I've also set it so if you select a date in the future, it will set the time to '09:00' which is the first available time within the `allowTimes`:

```
    var checkPastTime = function(currentDateTime) {

    var d = new Date();
    var todayDate = d.getDate();


    if (currentDateTime.getDate() == todayDate) { // check today date
        this.setOptions({               
            minTime: d.getHours() + '1:00' //here pass current time hour                        ;
        });
    } else
        this.setOptions({
            minTime: false
        });

    if(currentDateTime.getDate() == todayDate && d.getHours() >= 17) {
        this.setOptions({               
            minDate:'+1970/01/02',
            minTime: '09:00',
            defaultTime: '09:00'
        });     
    }   

    };

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('en'); 

    var d = new Date();
    var todayDate = d.getDate();


    if(todayDate == d.getDay() + 1) {
        var ahead = d.getHours() + 1;
    } else {
        var ahead = '9';
    }

    jQuery('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
        //beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        format: 'd/m/Y H:i a',
        minDate: 0, 
        onChangeDateTime: checkPastTime,
        onShow: checkPastTime, 
        defaultTime: ahead + ':00',
        step: "30",
         allowTimes:[
          '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30',
          '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00'
         ]              
    });         

  });
```

Comment: Just need a way now for it to now write the current time prior to selecting both date and time now...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
var m = (Math.ceil(minutes/30) * 30) % 60;
currentDate.setMinutes(m);
```

and then set `currentDate` into your datetimepicker as `defaultDate` or some method `setDate`

Comment: Thanks @step - How would you use this with the code I have supplied?

Comment: Before ask please use documentation of anything you solving at fisrt.

Comment: I have checked but still not of the wiser @step